# Error when knitting my .Rmd file with Python code using reticulate

Tags: python, r

When I try to knit a .Rmd file with a simple trunk of python code, it failed. However, when I use `repl_python()` function in `reticulate` package, all python code runs smoothly in console command line.

When typing `py_available()`, it returns `TRUE`.

Hence, I think there's no error of my Python configuration. I cannot figure out what's wrong with my R Markdown file.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Malcolm"
date: "2019/11/21"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup}
library(reticulate)
#conda_create("r-reticulate") # I created a new conda environment
#conda_install("r-reticulate", "scipy") # and I installed all python libraries I need.
#conda_install("r-reticulate", "pandas")
#conda_install("r-reticulate", "seaborn")
use_condaenv("r-reticulate")
py_module_available('pandas')
```

```{python}
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from scipy.stats import f
from scipy.stats import boxcox

r = f.rvs(30, 30, size=500)
np.random.seed(1234) 
transformed,fitted_lambda = boxcox(r)
print('lambda=',fitted_lambda)
sns.distplot(r, rug=True,color='green')
sns.distplot(transformed, rug=True)
```
````

And the result turns out:

```
Quitting from lines 34-37 (reticulate.Rmd) 
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : ImportError: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy c-extensions failed.
- Try uninstalling and reinstalling numpy.
- If you have already done that, then:
  1. Check that you expected to use Python3.8 from "C:\PROGRA~1\R\R-36~1.1\bin\x64\Rterm.exe",
     and that you have no directories in your PATH or PYTHONPATH that can
     interfere with the Python and numpy version "1.17.3" you're trying to use.
  2. If (1) looks fine, you can open a new issue at
     https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues.  Please include details on:
     - how you installed Python
     - how you installed numpy
     - your operating system
     - whether or not you have multiple versions of Python installed
     - if you built from source, your compiler versions and ideally a build log

- If you're working with a numpy git repository, try `git clean -xdf`
  (removes all files not under version control) and rebuild numpy.

Note: this error has many possible
Calls: <Anonymous> ... py_capture_output -> force -> <Anonymous> -> py_call_impl
停止执行
```

P.S.  When I use `py_module_available('libraryname')` to check the packages needed, they all return `FALSE`.  Although I use `conda_install("r-reticulate", "libraryname")`, it does not work. Could anyone successfully knit my simple Python code above using your R Markdown?

I tried both CRAN and development version of `reticulate`, which all failed.

my R environment is :

```
sessionInfo()
```

```
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17763)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936 
[2] LC_CTYPE=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                              
[5] LC_TIME=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
[6] methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] reticulate_1.13

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.2      lattice_0.20-38 png_0.1-7      
 [4] digest_0.6.21   grid_3.6.1      jsonlite_1.6   
 [7] evaluate_0.14   blogdown_0.16   rlang_0.4.0    
[10] Matrix_1.2-17   rmarkdown_1.16  tools_3.6.1    
[13] xfun_0.10       yaml_2.2.0      compiler_3.6.1 
[16] htmltools_0.4.0 knitr_1.25
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My experience is, if you have same problem, use your git and roll back to former commit version, the problem will be solved. :D

```
git reset
```